# Open Battery Settings in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I found flutter packages to open battery settings https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings and https://pub.dev/packages/open_settings but they don't provide to open battery settings in android. Do you have any suggestion?

[image: Settings -> Battery]

Answer (score 0):

u can add it manually to your project with link
https://github.com/spencerccf/app_settings/blob/master/lib/app_settings.dart

```
/// Future async method call to open battery optimization settings.
static Future<void> openBatteryOptimizationSettings({
bool asAnotherTask = false,
}) async {
_channel.invokeMethod('battery_optimization', {
'asAnotherTask': asAnotherTask,
});
}
```

Comment: This is batteryOptimization and I'm not looking for it. I'm looking basic battery-settings.

Comment: @Sha I think u have to change battery_optimization with battery_manager

Comment: nope didn’t work.